# How do I write a function to permanently change a passed string

Tags: c, string, function

If i have `char* str;` how do I write a function that accepts `str` and can make changes to `str` so that, the changes persist after the function returns?

what I have is:

```
char *str = (char *) malloc(10);
sprintf(str, "%s", "123456789");
//str points to 1
move_ptr(&str);
//str points to 2

void move_ptr(char** str)
{
    *str++;
}
```

is there a better way to do that?

Comment: Be careful: if you increment the pointer 'str' you throw away the handle to the allocated memory, and therefore create a memory leak.

Comment: Johnathan makes a good point, although it's worse than a leak: if you increment the only pointer you have to your *malloc*ed memory and attempt to **free(str)** the incremented value, your program will almost certainly crash.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Just access the data through the pointer, in the function:

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void change_string(char *str)
{
  size_t i;

  /* As an example, make it all upper case. */
  for(i = 0; str[i]; ++i)
    str[i] = toupper(str[i]);
}

int main(void)
{
  char buffer[32];
  char *str = buffer;

  strcpy(str, "test string");
  change_string(str);
  printf("it's now %s\n", str);

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Come to think of it, you'll notice that the standard `strcpy()` function is exactly of the category you describe. It's a very common operation in C.

UPDATED: The question has been significantly rewritten, now it seems to be more about changing the pointer itself, rather than the data. Perhaps this was the meaning all along, but I didn't understand.

The solution in the question is fine, but personally I find it more convenient to work with return values, if possible:

```
char * change_pointer(char *str)
{
  return str + 1;
}

int main(void)
{
  char *str = "test string";

  printf("now '%s'\n", str);
  str = change_pointer(str);
  printf("now '%s'\n", str);
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

The pointer(s) could of course also be `const`-declared, and *should* be if no changes to the buffered text are needed.

Comment: What if I want to change the position in str that str points to, do I have to use a function that takes a char **str as param and then pass str in as &str?

Comment: @unknown: That sounds like a different question ... But of course that's one way of solving it. If possible, I prefer to use the return value, so that the function returns the updated string pointer.

Answer (score 2):

*Question changed*

<s>If your pointer points to readonly data, you can't change what it points to.</s>

When one writes

```
char *data = "forty two";
```

that "forty two" is readonly data; and you can't change what the pointer `data` points to whether directly or through a function call.

To get a 'string' initialized from a literal constant, instead of assigning a pointer to the literal constant, copy the characters to an array

```
char data[] = "forty two";
```

Now data is an array of 10 characters (9 for the letters and space + 1 for the NUL terminator) which you can change at will.

Answer (score 0):

Your example may be over simplified, but just in case... Be careful of doing things like this because you're going to leak memory. After your function call, you no longer have a pointer to (part of) the original memory you allocated.

As mentioned by *unwind*, returning the new pointer may be a better choice. While it achieves the same goal, it makes it more obvious that you need to keep the original pointer around for the purposes of releasing the memory. The counter argument being that it gives the impression that you can free the original pointer once you have the return value, which you can't do because they both point at (different locations) in the same memory block.

Comment: It's worse than just a leak, calls to **free()** with _any value not returned by_ **malloc()** will almost certainly cause a crash.